# Can't create a class within intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Edit: The solution to the problem was to uninstall and re-download and install intelliJ.

I am unable to create a class following online tutorials. One method is to expand the project folder and right click src and from there you can create a class, but I am unable to expand the project folder in intellij and therefore am unable to access the src file to create a class. The tutorial video shows an arrow next to the project that you can click to expand the project, but I don't have this arrow. Please help I am new.[intellijScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmzyy.png)

This is the tutorial I used: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

I created the SRC folder like someone suggested and now the project expands, but there still is no option to create a class.

Comment: Please post the link to the tutorial you are following, provide more information about your problems so others can help you better.

Comment: You probably don't have this arrow, because the folder is empty. The standard project-directory is `C:\Users\<You>\IdeaProjects`. If you want to have the `\src` folder, just manually create it in there.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be an issue in the way the project was setup. When you create a new project, IJ creates three things in your project, a src folder, a .idea folder, and a .iml file. Without the .idea folder and .iml file it wouldn't let me create a new class either. Delete your HelloWorld project, and try again. If still no luck, maybe try uninstalling/ reinstalling. Could possibly be an issue with the JDK, I don't mess with that, I just use 11 version 11.0.6.... Hope this helps!